# Eclipse showing a warning when Bundle-Classpath has a system property

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, tycho

I have an external library set at my Bundle-ClassPath which will be located at different paths in Windows and Linux.
So I've declared the Bundle-ClassPath using a system property as follows:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 external:$path_to_my_lib$
```

It's all compiling and running as it should. But Eclipse is showing a warning.

> 'source.external:$path_to_my_lib$' build entry is missing

What should I do to solve it?

Comment: There is a bug report for Tycho builds covering this [370958](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=370958) - which just says it was fixed to give a warning rather than a failure. Everything I have seen about 'external:' says it is a pain to use and best avoided.

Comment: 'external:' is not OSGi standard. It is an Eclipse containerism. You really should not use.